# Safari download bar rar file icon show as VLC icon,which associate to The Unarchiver should shows its icon

Tags: macos, safari, icon

Safari download bar rar shows file icon as VLC icon, but .rar is associated with  associate to The Unarchiver and should show its icon

[image: Show the icon]

Comment: You listen to Katy Perry? High five dude. And I thought I was the only KatyCat here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, we need to Clear Mac OS X's icon cache.Here is how:

1. To get started, close all open applications and then launch Terminal from Macintosh HD > Applications > Utilities. Copy and paste the following command at the Terminal prompt and press Return to execute it:
2. `sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name 'com.apple.dock.iconcache' -delete
   sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name 'com.apple.iconservices' -delete
   sudo rm -r /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store`
3. restart,job done.

Answer (score 3):

If you want .rar to be opened with The Unarchiver as default, you can:

1. Get info on this .rar file
2. Set file to open with in the info window
3. Click Change All

The Change All button will make all .rar be opened with The Unarchiver and have The Unarchiver icon on it.

Comment: This is the best solution if it's not opening in Unarchiver, but I think the question was more related to the .rar file not having the right icon. Rebuilding the icon cache with the steps below will fix the icon, Get Info method will fix the application in which it opens.

Comment: Ok. I thought the default affects the icons. Thanks though